# AWK for checking first columns of different files line by line and see differences

Tags: shell, awk, command-line

I have 2 files like this:

File1:

```
fa65c95d0  ./checklist.chk
316856ab2  ./.vscode/settings.json
6075df9cc  ./sha256sum.txt
36d59e45b  ./md5sum.txt
```

File2:

```
fa65c95d0  ./checklist.chk
222222222  ./.vscode/settings.json
644ddd555  ./sha256sum.txt
36d59e45b  ./md5sum.txt
```

And I want to compare first columns on those files line by line to see what is different on File2.

Desired output

```
./.vscode/settings.json is modified
./sha256sum.txt is modified
```

I searched on net and tried to do with comm but this script doesn't exactly meet my requests

```
comm -3 sum1.txt sum2.txt | awk '$1 {print $2}'
```

Output for this

```
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
./.vscode/settings.json
./.vscode/settings.json
./sha256sum.txt
./md5sum.txt
./sha256sum.txt
./md5sum.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to post their efforts in their question which they have put in order to solve their own problem, kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thanks for welcome sorry to not adding attempts I just forgot, I've been trying something for half an hour and I'm confused.

Comment: @Varian, Thanks for adding your efforts, keep it up and happy learning on this great site SO, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]=$1
  next
}
($2 in a) && a[$2]!=$1{
  print $0,"is modified"
}
' Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$2]=$1                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is $2 and value is $1for current line.
  next                            ##next will skip all statements from here.
}                                 ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR here.
($2 in a) && a[$2]!=$1{           ##Checking condition if 2nd field of Input_file2 is present in array a AND value of array a with index $2 is NOT equal to $1 of Input_file2 then do following.
  print $0,"is modified"          ##Printing current line the string is modified as per OP need.
}                                 ##Closing BLOCK of statements which were getting executed for Input_file2.
' Input_file1  Input_file2        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `diff(1)`:

```
diff file1 file2
```

```
2,3c2,3
< 316856ab2  ./.vscode/settings.json
< 6075df9cc  ./sha256sum.txt
---
> 222222222  ./.vscode/settings.json
> 644ddd555  ./sha256sum.txt
```

Or unified diff:

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

```
--- file1   2019-12-02 18:44:46.525142623 +0100
+++ file2   2019-12-02 18:44:57.253178157 +0100
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 fa65c95d0  ./checklist.chk
-316856ab2  ./.vscode/settings.json
-6075df9cc  ./sha256sum.txt
+222222222  ./.vscode/settings.json
+644ddd555  ./sha256sum.txt
 36d59e45b  ./md5sum.txt
```

Or `vimdiff(1)`:

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

[image: how vimdiff shows the difference]

Comment: IMHO, if I am not wrong, `diff` provides output if both files column vice lines are same correct? Else it will give each line difference. Kindly do lemme know if  this is correct, just for my understanding only, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: It actually provides you with a valid patch that will bring the first file to the state of the second file